# ASP.NET HtmlInputHidden control - stop name from changing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page and I'm trying to add a couple of hidden HTML input controls. I will be submitting this form to another site (PP) so I need the names of the controls to NOT change when rendered. Is there a way to make ASP.NET honor the name property that I set in the code-behind?

As an alternate, I don't need to dynamically create these controls, I can also just assign the value to an existing HTML field but I don't know how to do that with ASP.NET/C#

Comment: What version of asp.net are you using? If you're using .NET 4, it would make things easier... e.g. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using ASP.NET 4.0? You can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) on the control with a value of static, and the ID will not change.

Otherwise you could use a literal to output the  element itself or just its value.
On you're page you'd have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ppID" value='<asp:Literal ID="ppIDValue" runat="server" />' />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" id="ppID" value="<%= ppIDValue %>" />
```

And in the code behind or wherever:

```
this.ppIDValue.Text = "value for ppID";
```

or (abbreviated):

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public string ppIDValue = "0";
    override OnLoad()
    { this.ppIDValue = "100"; }
}
```

Comment: Im using ASP.NET 3.5. Can you give an example of the literal output?

Comment: I'm confused - the question mentions the names not changing, but this answer addresses the ID - two separate things on an input element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with putting literals inside HTML-tags is that the literals are very likely to, at some annoying point in time, to be removed from the designer-codebehind file. Even though you could manually add them, this will in most case screw up the mapping between the GUI-based editor and the designer-codebehind.

Further, if you are using Master Pages, they will anyway change the value of the name-attribute on your hidden fields.

I have been in search for the best way to do this myself, and was just about to write my own custom control, so I could preserve the value of the name-attribute. Then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687414/2521319) to a similar question, where Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("ppID", "1234") was mentioned. Bingo!