# Keeping a hidden input box name the same using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, input

I am trying to integrate with a payment gateway. They require a set of hidden input boxes to be posted to their gateway like:

```
<input id="orderref" name="orderref" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
```

I have added runat="server" so I can dynamically populate the boxes with values.

However, of course at runtime the input box name gets changed to:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$orderref" type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_orderref" value="9" />
```

I'm in a catch 22. If I remove runat="server" all is fine with regards to the name, but I then can't populate the input box with values! Is there a means to force the name of the field to stay the same?

Comment: you could populate them using javascript

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to rely on JavaScript when a good 8% of our site visitors have it switched off!

Comment: I had to write something similar some time ago and ended up just putting a placeholder on the page and filling it directly with the `<input ...>` elements (no runat=server).

Comment: @Heinzi Sorry, but can you elaborate I'm a noob at .net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what .NET version you are using the control over this differs: basically, pre-.NET4 you can only *alter* the container prefix by implementing your own, but *from* .NET4 you can [omit the container prefixes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) using `ClientIDMode`.

Alternatively, you may expose methods, say, on your page or master page and then call them using inline-scripting (`<%=MyMethodReturningValue() %>`) which is evaluated at the time of render.

EDIT:

To elaborate a little on my second suggestion, you can define a method in your pages code-behind that can be executed in an inline manner by use of [embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx); the referenced link gives simple examples of this, but the methods needn't be in `<script>` blocks of the page itself (as I previously touched on) so that you can keep your logic separated, such as:

Define a method in your page's code-behind:

```
public string RenderMessage()
{
    return "This need not be a hard-coded string!";
}
```

Write out your `input` element, omitting the `runat` attribute, and adding the embedded code block in place of where the value would be (think of this as a place holder); this code block is going to call the specified method on pre-render, and essentially be replaced by the returning value:

```
<input id="orderref" name="orderref" type="hidden" value='<%=RenderMessage() %>'/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the second bit. I'm a bit of a noob at the moment!

Comment: Check out this link on [Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx).

Comment: You missed the Response.Write on your code. RenderMessage() string will not apear on input value unless you Response.Write it

Comment: No, that's not true. The `<%= %>` syntax is shorthand for Response.write().

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira You are editing my answer to break the code - toxaq is correct.

Comment: True! Did not realise the '=' there. My bad

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0, you can set `clientidmode="Static"` on the `<input>` which will cause the ID to stay exactly as you set it. There are caveats to this, but in general should work for your needs.

[Documentation on ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

**Edit:** As it turns out, they need the name attribute to be static, which ClientIDMode does not control, and can not be set programatically in ASP.NET, it only controls the id attribute.

Comment: I've added the code, but its the **name** attribute I want to preserve not the ID.

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb I'm sorry, missed that in the original question. ClientIDMode does only affect the id attribute. You can't programatically set the name of a runat="server" as far as I know, so you may be left with one of the other options presented like writing to a placeholder, or removing the runat="server" and writing the value to that hidden control at runtime with <%=%>

Comment: Although I didn't use your solution. The info will be useful so thanks for your help.

Comment: Only works for id attribute. Name attribute cannot be controlled.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("orderref", "9")`

This creates the following hidden input:

`<input id="orderref" name="orderref" type="hidden" value="9" />`

For more details see [System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerhiddenfield.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this issue and eventually found the following solution:
In the markup I have the following: 
    `<%=html %>`

In the codebehind I have a protected variable: 
    `protected string html;`

I then set this variable as follows:
        `html = "<input id='Express_Receipt_Email' type='hidden' value='" + sessionUser.EmailAddress + "' name='Express_Receipt_Email'>";`